# Sikuli: moveTo method

Tags: sikuli

I am doing a POC on Sikuli, stuck with an issue using moveTo() method.

Error received: `TypeError: moveTo(): 1st arg can't be coerced to org.sikuli.script.Location`

All lines of code written were as per Sikuli tutorial on their website.

Not able to proceed further, any help asap will very much appreciated.

Following is the code:

```
region_1 = Region(110,320,99,23)
region_2.moveTo(region_1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moveTo()` method accepts `location` object as parameter.

This is a common mistake which happens while using Sikuli.

Try correcting your code to :

```
region_1 = Region(110,320,99,23)
location_1 = Location(x,y)
region_1.moveTo(location_1)
```

Refer to below url for more information on Sikuli Region:

http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohh I feel silly now. This works.